# Using Django ListView with custom query

Tags: django

I have a set of django models that are set out as follows:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    ...

class FooVersion(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    version = models.FloatField()
    ...
```

I'm trying to create a Django ListView that displays all Foos, in alphabetical order by the name of their highest version.  For example, if I have a data set that looks like:

```
version_id | id |           version_name            | version 
-----------+----+-----------------------------------+---------
         1 | 1  | Test 1                            |      1.0
         2 | 1  | Test 2                            |      2.0
         3 | 1  | Test 2                            |      3.0
         4 | 2  | Test 1                            |      1.0
         5 | 1  | Test 3                            |      2.5
         6 | 3  | Test 3                            |      1.0
```

I want the query to return:

```
version_id | id |           version_name            | version 
-----------+----+-----------------------------------+---------
         4 | 2  | Test 1                            |      1.0
         3 | 1  | Test 2                            |      3.0
         6 | 3  | Test 3                            |      1.0
```

The raw sql I would use to generate this is:

```
SELECT version_class.id as version_id, someapp_foo.id, version_class.name as version_name, version_class.version
FROM someapp_foo
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT someapp_fooversion.name, someapp_fooversion.version, someapp_fooversion.parent_id, someapp_fooversion.id
    FROM someapp_fooversion
    INNER JOIN(
        SELECT parent_id, max(version) AS version
    FROM courses_courseversion GROUP BY parent_id)
AS current_version ON current_version.parent_id = someapp_fooversion.parent_id
AND current_version.version = someapp_fooversion.version)
AS version_class ON version_class.parent_id = someapp_foo.id
ORDER BY version_name;
```

But I'm having trouble using a raw query because the RawQuerySet object doesn't have a 'count' method, which is called by ListView for pagination.  I've looked into the 'extra' feature of Django querysets, but I'm having trouble formulating a query that will work with that.

How would I formulate a query for 'extra' that would get me what I'm looking for?  Or is there a way to convert a RawQuerySet into a regular QuerySet?  Any other possible solutions to get the results I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way to do this, but for now I'm trying a custom solution that seems to work:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.query import RawQuerySet

class CountableRawQuerySet(RawQuerySet):
   def count(self):
       return sum([1 for obj in self])

class FooManager(models.Manager):
    def raw(self, raw_query, params=None, *args, **kwargs):
        return CountableRawQuerySet(raw_query=raw_query, model=self.model, params=params, using=self._db, *args, **kwargs)

class Foo(models.Model):
    objects = FooManager()
```

Then my queryset is:

```
Foo.objects.raw(sql)
```

Suggestions on how to improve this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all - your solution is wrong and very uneffective with a big amount of data.
I believe you just need something like:

```
from django.db.models import Max
Foo.objects.annotate(max_version=Max(fooversion__version))
```

You can now reffer to `max_version` attribute in each result as to normal attribute.
Please see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/ for details.

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for, but I'm guessing the solution is close.  What I'm trying to order by is the name that is associated with the max version, not the max version (which could be thrown away as soon as I do the join if I wanted).  If I use 'Max' for both the version and the name, I seem to get the wrong name (i.e., whatever is alphabetically the max value, not the one actually associated with the max version). How would I get the real name information using annotate?

Comment: It seems you need also some magic with .extra() select also. I've done something similiar but can't find it at the moment.

Comment: The 'extra' was definitely one of the solutions I was looking at, but don't know how to make work for this particular situation.  Let me know if you think of anything.

Answer (score 0):

One other point to add is that RawQuerySet works fine with a ListView as long as you don't use pagination, i.e. you can just leave out the `paginate_by = NN` attribute from your ListView subclass.